# Pyro CMS - trying to move files/folders up a directory level

Tags: pyrocms

I did a Pyro test installation at mydomain.com/pyro, and now that I have the site configured, I wanted to move everything up to the root directory. It worked fine, except for when I leave off the "www" in my URL, so:

- 'www.mydomain.com' works fine, all of the navigational links point to the right pages
- 'mydomain.com' does not work, all of the navigational links still point to the '/pyro/' test directory

I can't find anything in the config files or the database to change this.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

- Have you tried clearing you page cache? Utilities > Maintenance then under Cache Maintenance
- Have you checked the `default_pages.uri` and `default_pages.slug` columns in your database?